# String Slicing based on keyword

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

In below String I want to extract siteID (5 digit numeric id after "=") to get the value in new dataframe , I need efficient code as I have to perform this task for over 0.5 million rows.

```
FSP10001GFelt
Label=G_4201_K1108_SHMAIIGNDA_3, SiteID=32013
Label=G_MUNUNGA_QUARRY_1, SiteID=26241, LogicRNCID=3
```

Comment: You should say more about how your input is formatted. But better is if you try something yourself first. It could be that the string method `split` is what you want. Or regular expressions.

Comment: Besides, not everyone outside India/Pakistan knows what a lakh is. It's 10000, isn't it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Arndt Jonasson said, you could use a regular expression:

```
import re

my_string = '''FSP10001GFelt
Label=G_4201_K1108_SHMAIIGNDA_3, SiteID=32013
Label=G_MUNUNGA_QUARRY_1, SiteID=26241, LogicRNCID=3'''

re.findall('(?<=SiteID=)\d+', my_string)  # returns ['32013', '26241']
```

Comment: Thanks Arndt,  this code is working fine for string , could you please suggest how this code can be used over a data frame.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way via `pandas`. I suggest you benchmark to see what performs best with your data and set-up.

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

mystr = StringIO("""FSP10001GFelt
Label=G_4201_K1108_SHMAIIGNDA_3, SiteID=32013
Label=G_MUNUNGA_QUARRY_1, SiteID=26241, LogicRNCID=3""")

# replace mystr with 'file.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(mystr, skiprows=1, usecols=[1], header=None, sep=', ', index_col=False)

res = list(map(int, df[1].str.split('=').str[-1]))

# [32013, 26241]
```

Comment: I would key off SiteID, not the equal.  It is not clear how many equals may be in any particlar string.

Comment: Of course, but that may be more costly. The right solution depends on the data.

Answer (score 0):

I would use RegEx for this kind of task because of its flexibility and simplicity.

Here's a working example:

```
import re

data = "FSP10001GFelt\nLabel=G_4201_K1108_SHMAIIGNDA_3, SiteID=32013\nLabel=G_MUNUNGA_QUARRY_1, SiteID=26241, LogicRNCID=3"
matches = re.findall(r'.*SiteID=(\d+).*', data)

for match in matches:
    print match
```